# How to optimization data transfer(backup, sync) from local to remote server in Cassandra?

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, cassandra

I am using Cassandra db 3.7 for the real time capturing of the data. I have be running it for a year. Now data is very big(around 100 GB). Lets say in feature it will be around 1 TB if more data is being captured.

Now first I started searching for some ETL tools to do the work for me. I looked and tried ETL software's like Talend ETL, Jaspersoft ETL and Spoon. But they were **not supporting Cassandra 3.7**.

So now I wrote a asp.net windows application that will read 500 records each time from Cassandra db form local using datastax dll and send those to remote WCF service which will insert them into remote Cassandra db.

It works well but man it is taking too much time.

**Problem 1:** Getting all the partition keys.

I am getting all the partition keys(all distinct primary keys) and saving into log and then looping through these partition key. Now if the sync fails in between I will restart the process by using last processed partition key.

But my problem is **I cant able to get the list of distinct partition keys** using

```
Select distinct p1,p2 from table;
```

The above statement is failing when data is big.

**Problem 2:** How can we make the read/write faster.

If somehow i can read form db faster like bulk read/write(if in case there is one) I can speed up the process a little.

**Problem 3:** WCF can handle only few requests and limited send and receive data size. Which is limiting me from running multiple instances of application.

I can run multiple WCF services at once for each instance of application. But don't see it a good solution considering data size.

I am expecting ETL, backup, snapshot tools are more faster. Can any explain how they are faster.

Comment: Have you tried the spark connector or cqlsh's copy?

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Thanks for suggestion. I didn't try spark connector. I will look into it once. Regarding cqlsh's copy will copy data to csv files right. My requirement is to send them to remote server.

Comment: @ChrisLohfink And also I can create csv files and then import them into remote server. But I don't want to do it manually. I want to automate the process.